# how to display data from textbox to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, frontend

I want to collect data in the form of a paragraph in the text box and then show that to a new page. I have added code for HTML for the announcement page (from where I want to take data and show it there as well),  and for the archive page ( where I want to show the data), How should I do it? Kindly help me out. I am new to HTML therefore I am not sure if I am doing this the right.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylem.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <head>
        <title>Announcement Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="Post" action="archive.html">
            <textarea type="text" id="textbox" class="textbox" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()"/>
    
        </form>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Archive
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylea.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    
       <h2> Announcement : <span id="result-text"> </span> </h2>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```
    function handleSubmit (){
        const textbox = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
    
        localStorage.setItem("Data", textbox);
    
        return;
    }
```

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
        const textbox = params.get('textbox');
    
        document.getElementById('result-text').innerHTML= textbox;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your "Data" into local storage so you need to access it there instead of trying to pull it from the document location

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('Data');

    document.getElementById('result-text').innerHTML = data;
});
```

Comment: the data is there in the local storage ( I inspected the local storage to see the data there) and I tried to add it to the archive.html but it is not showing. you are saying insteadof document.get....byId
I should write localstorage.get...byId?

I am not getting anything except " Announcement" written on archive.html and I want the enter data in the textbox to that page as well

Comment: If you open up your dev console and paste this snippet localStorage.getItem('Data'); what does it give you? I would try it once on both pages after you've called setItem